# Amplify my 3.3V DAC signal to 220V

Tags: amplifier, high-voltage, dac

In one of my projects I need to generate different kind of 220V amplitude waveform signals in order to send commands to a heater using the pilot wire protocol. Here are the needed waveforms:

[image]

Is there a way to use a DAC and then amplify the output of the DAC to a 220V amplitude. If yes which circuit and components can I use.

Otherwise I am open to other price and size optimal circuits to get such waveforms.

Many thanks

Comment: You have not said a lot about the proposed load, or about the frequency range. Is 220V peak-to-peak or what?

Comment: Hi @SpehroPefhany, yes 220V is peak to peak, and the purpose of proposing a DAC is being able to generate multiple frequencies, even extremely low frequencies (under 1 Hz). For a clearer insight it's for a heater pilot wire for which you can find the needed waveforms at: https://goo.gl/CnnD1k

Comment: @TarikMokafih that’s just the voltage waveforms. What are the current requirements? Or line impedance?  Or frequency limits?

Comment: @EdgarBrown, Current requirements are as low as 50mA, Frequency as the image explains is 50Hz or less than 1Hz. Thanks

Comment: While it's possible to make the amplifier output you need high impedance, it isn't possible to make the power supply that will be required (220VDC+) high impedance - therefore, it will be very dangerous. This is a very slippery slope you are proposing to go down.

Comment: @DSWG, You don't think it's possible to use step by step amplification (5 times a 50 volt Op amp circuit) ?

Comment: An opamp can only put out the voltage you power it from.  So, you need like +-120V power rails for your opamp. Don't know of many opamps that can handle that.  You'd need a power transistor output stage to handle the voltage - and the current.   Typical opamps can only put out a few milliamperes - there are power opamps, but they are expensive, and probably won't do what you want.

Comment: Those are all modifications of the line voltage.  You can manage all of them by switching the line voltage through solid state relays and diodes.  A DAC and amplifier would be the expensive (and hard) way to generate those signals.

Comment: I have a very hard time believing that a 230VAC appliance requires 220 volt peak-to-peak to control, it would be crazy. Your diagram only shows different easy modifications of the standard AC voltage (which is not peak-to-peak)

Comment: The signal here is intended to be one easily *derived* from the mains supply, but it is a distinct wire not actually used to *power* the heater (input impedance is supposed to be >= 100K): http://www.radiateur-electrique.org/fil-pilote-radiateur.php (google translate renders something relatively readable if necessary)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for digging up the necessary information OP should have included!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DAC and amplifier would be the expensive and complicated way to control the heater.

You have 230VAC at hand - you must, because that's what the heater operates on.

Use that 230VAC source, a few SSRs (solid state relays,) and a couple of diodes.

The control signal doesn't seem to drive the heating element directly.  The commands seem to be just that:  commands to a controller in the heater.  That means you don't have to switch high power, and can use small SSRs and diodes to make the control signals.

Take the simple cases first:

1. Confort
2. Confort -1
3. Confort -2
4. Eco ou reduit

All four can be handled by one relay:

1. Relay open
2. Cycle relay 4 min 57 seconds off, 3 seconds on
3. Cycle relay 4 min 53 seconds off, 7 seconds on
4. Relay on

Each of the other two cases require a diode and relay each.  Put a diode in series with each relay, each diode points in a different direction.

Now, you turn off the main relay, and turn on one of the two relays with a diode.  Each sends a different command

1. Use zero crossing SSRs.  These switch when the AC voltage crosses zero volts.
2. Use SSRs rated for use on 230VAC.
3. Use diodes rated with a peak inverse voltage of more than 300V.
4. Use diodes rated to handle more current than the command circuit requires.

Doing that, you can use three digital outputs from a microprocessor to send all commands.

---

Be very careful when working with 230VAC. There are many safety practices you should follow: look them up, learn them, apply them.  **Failure to do so can kill you.**

There are many design practices to follow when designing and laying out circuits that use 230VAC.  Look them up.  Learn them.  Follow them.  **Failure to do so might burn down your house or electrocute you or someone using the device.**

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I guess I can use Triacs instead of relays, right ?

Comment: SSRs isolate your low voltage microprocessor from the line voltage.  If you can safely do it with triacs, then that's OK.

Comment: OptoTriacs may do the trick I guess

Comment: An SSR is an optotriac with additional circuitry built in to provide safety and reliability when things go wrong.  So, you could probably use bare optotriacs - if the additional risk is small enough that you can use the cheaper part.

Answer (score 0):

A common-base transistor will do this. Drive the emitter from a current-output DAC. Tie the collector thru 100,000 ohm resistor to 220 volts DC. Peak current will be (at 10uA/volt) 2 milliAmps. Power power dissipation will be 1mA * 110 volts, or 0.11 watts. Be sure 0.11 watts is Safe Operating Area acceptable.

Comment: Perhaps, but application to *existing* appliances doesn't actually require arbitrary signals, but only those which can be derived simply via rectification and gating of the mains supply waveform.